# Display imported data in reverse order, so that the most recent entries are on top

Tags: google-sheets, importdata

I want to invert the spreadsheet so I get the data at the top every day.

I've tried to

```
=sort(importdata("=importdata("http://www.tr4der.com/download/historical-prices/SPY/"),1,false)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Would anyone know how to invert the .csv file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the easiest way to achieve the descending sort:

```
=sort(importdata("http://www.tr4der.com/download/historical-prices/SPY/"),3,false)
```

Comment: Thank you, but may you explain how you came with the 3 in order to sort? What did the 3 do?

Comment: 3 is the column index to sort by.  In this case your 3rd column  is the date column

Answer (score 2):

Applying `sort` is certainly the easiest, it sometimes results in the header row getting sorted to the bottom or middle of the table. In such situations `query` can help, as it allows one to specify the number of header rows. The query string `select * order by Col3 desc` sorts by 3rd column, descending.

```
=query(importdata("http://www.tr4der.com/download/historical-prices/SPY/"), "select * order by Col3 desc", 1)
```

The number 1 here indicates that the data has 1 header row.